# Getting error in Synapse: "Resolving CosmosDB path has failed with error Incorrect account or region" error?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-synapse

Recently been getting error in our Synapse query: Resolving CosmosDB path has failed with error 'Incorrect account or region'.

Prior to today our query is working. I checked the account, region, and Primary Read-only Key and it has not changed. Does anyone know where else I should check to resolve it?

```
SELECT
    -- queried fields here
FROM OPENROWSET (
    'CosmosDB', N'account=ACCOUNT;database=DATABASE;region=North Central US;key=PrimaryReadOnlyKey',ContainerObject
) AS LWDocs2
```

Comment: Are you using serverless sql pool or dedicated sql pool ?

Comment: @Balaji Serverless SQL Pool

Comment: Since this requires troubleshooting, I would recommend filing a support ticket for deeper investigation. Follow the steps in this document [Create an Azure support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request)

Answer (score 0):

If you see the [prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-cosmos-db-analytical-store?tabs=openrowset-key#prerequisites) for querying cosmos db. from Synapse analytics make sure **your Azure Cosmos DB analytical storage is in the same region as serverless SQL pool.**

When you use `region` in the query you need specify the region where cosmos db is present other than thar region will give you an error which you are getting.

You can try without specifying region in query.

```sql
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM OPENROWSET( 
       'CosmosDB',
       'Account=cosmos-acc-name;Database=database-name;Key=access-key',
       Ecdc) as documents
```

**My execution and Outputs:**

- With wrong region:
  [image]
- With Correct region:
  [image]